How to initialize a SWIG wrapped C structure from a python byte array?
I am working on a project which has some python files which are using some SWIG wrapped C data structures.
I have some raw bytes I am passing into the python code which I would like to use to initialize the struct directly. Is there any easy way to do this?
For example
`C struct

struct st{
    uint16_t foo;
    uint16_t bar;
}


Python code
    bytes_val_st = 12345.to_bytes(4, 'big') 
    obj = st()`

What is the best way to initialize the struct? Can I extend the SWIG struct define with a constructor or is there an easier way to do it directly?
Thank you
I have tried a few things, passing the bytes to the struct, creating a constructor. I am pretty stuck thank you
